# Oracle update from random on another table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have some fields in table1 to update with random values from some fields in table2.

I have to random into rows of table2 and update each rows of table1 with the same rows values of table2.

Here is my SQL code, but it doesn't work.

```
update owner.table1 t1
  set (t1.adress1, t1.zip_code, t1.town) = (select t2.adress, t2.zip_code, t2.town 
                                            from table1 t2 
                                            where id = trunc(dbms_random.value(1,20000)))
```

Result: all rows are updated with the same values, like no random on table 2 rows

Comment: oops, after control, it update nothing. don't know where is the matter

Answer (score 0):

How about switching to analytic ROW_NUMBER function? It doesn't really create a *random* value, but might be good enough.

Here's an example: first, create test tables and insert some data:

```
SQL> create table t1 (id number,address varchar2(20), town varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 (id number, address varchar2(20), town varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1
  2    select 1, 'Ilica 20', 'Zagreb' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Petrinjska 30', 'Sisak' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'Stradun 12', 'Dubrovnik' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> insert into t2
  2    select 1, 'Pavelinska 15', 'Koprivnica' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Baščaršija 11', 'Sarajevo' from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'Riva 22', 'Split' from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * From t1 order by id;

        ID ADDRESS              TOWN
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Ilica 20             Zagreb
         2 Petrinjska 30        Sisak
         3 Stradun 12           Dubrovnik

SQL> select * From t2 order by id;

        ID ADDRESS              TOWN
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Pavelinska 15        Koprivnica
         2 Baščaršija 11        Sarajevo
         3 Riva 22              Split
```

Update t1 with rows from t2:

```
SQL> update t1 set
  2    (t1.address, t1.town) =
  3    (select x.address, x.town
  4     from (select row_number() over (order by address) id, t2.address, t2.town
  5           from t2
  6          ) x
  7     where x.id = t1.id);

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * From t1 order by id;

        ID ADDRESS              TOWN
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 Baščaršija 11        Sarajevo
         2 Pavelinska 15        Koprivnica
         3 Riva 22              Split

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi thank's for your help Littlefoot.

Your code can't do the job. id's are not the same in table 1 and table 2. And i have only 20 0000 rows in table2 for near to 300 000 in table 1
so i have to random and may be loop but i really don(t kown how to do the job.
does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Hi, the problem is fix, here is the solution : i have to force by adding this at the and of my SQL request : where id = trunc(dbms_random.value(1,20000))and T1.id<>id) it force sql to ierate on each row

Comment: I'm glad you did it. Thank you for letting us know